# Issue centering div to bottom right with tailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this card that is made with tailwindCSS.

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-3">
    <div class="px-3 mb-6 w-1/3">
        <div class="card card-panel">
            <div class="mx-3 my-3">
                <div class="sunpart">
                    <div class="content-sunpart ">
                        <div class="title">Ma part de soleil</div>
                        <div class="chart-wrapper "></div>
                        <div class="circlevalue">52
                            <span class="percent">%</span> <span class="suninfo">de soleil</span></div>
                        <div class="sunvalue resize">Soit</div>
                        <div class="sunvalue orange">12</div>
                        <div class="sunvalue kwh">kWh</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with :

```
.sunvalue {
        width: 23%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 28px;
        right: 10px;
        color: #666;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

in `.sunvalue`, it is supposed to be aligned on the bottom right corner of the card, but it doesn't.

Same thing with `52% de soleil`, it is supposed to be vertically aligned with:

```
.circlevalue {
    top: 52%;
}
```

but it doesn't vertically center.

Can anybody explain me why and what should I do ?

Here is the full CSS definition I use:

With CSS:

```
.sunpart  {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    background: hsla(0,0%,98%,.6);

}

.sunpart .content-sunpart canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-48%);

}
.resize {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 15px;
    color: #1b577f;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.customer-wrapper .sidebar .sunpart .content-sunpart {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sunpart .chart-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15%;
    background: url(../images/soleil.png) no-repeat center center / 80% auto;
    //background: url(/static/media/soleil.746b1ea8.png) no-repeat 50%/80% auto;
}
.circlevalue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    color: #fe8e22;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

.circlevalue span.suninfo {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    left: 41%;
    top: 61%;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.sunvalue {
    width: 23%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 28px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: right;
}

.sunvalue.orange {
    font-size: 25px;
    bottom: 13px;
    right: 50px;
    color: #fe8e22;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.sunvalue.kwh {
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.mysunpart{
    height: 220px;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/xoco70/pen/GRoaNex)

Comment: Good point. Let me check it. I know I am using tailwindcss,  but I have a doubt for bootstrap

Comment: No, I'm using tailwindcss, I will include it in question, thanks

Comment: Please create a codepen for this.

Comment: @Digvijay codepen is done !

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind is a utility-first CSS framework. It means that you don't have to write all this CSS. Everything is happening by applying **tailwind specific classes**,. Such as *text-lg*, *px-3*, *mb-6* or *w-1/3*. As you have started to do.

For alignement issues, flexbox is one of the easiest solution.
You need to apply https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items (Vertical positioning)
or https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content (Horizontal positioning)

I'm not sure of how exactly you want it to be, but here is an example using only tailwind classes (no custom css).

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.5.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative w-full text-gray-600 p-3 h-32">
  <div class="absolute flex items-center justify-center inset-0 bg-gray-200">
    <div class="flex flex-col text-center">
      <span class="text-orange-500 text-4xl font-bold">52%</span>
      <span class="font-light">de soleil</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="relative w-full h-full flex justify-between">
    <div class="text-lg text-blue-800 font-semibold">Ma part de soleil</div>
    <div class="flex flex-col text-right text-xs mt-auto">
      <span>Soit</span>
      <span class="text-xl text-orange-500 font-bold leading-none">12</span>
      <span class="font-semibold">kWh</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```